# Read iOS Bundle information

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, bundle

I want to know what the **bundle version**/id in my current app of an extern application on an iOS device.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to know what the bundle version of a *different* (read: **not developed by you**) app is? That's not possible.

Comment: It's also developed by me. Is it possible to read with through a bundle identifier?

Comment: You can use custom URL schemes, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're in a App Sandbox. You can't communicate with other apps than yours.

To get the Version of your running app:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]
```

Comment: wrong answer.. It'll give you the app version of your app not the other app

Comment: As I said "To get the Version of your running app". It's an additional information, if you'd need it.

Comment: Useful answer even if it isn't for this specific question! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the other application is developed by you, you can use [custom URL schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) to determine whether a specific version is installed.

For each version that you want to check against, you'll have to add a URL scheme to your other app. The idea is that the URL schemes only contain a URL scheme for the current and previous versions.

Version *1.0* would only have `com.you.your-other-app.1.0`.
Version *1.2*, however, then has two or more URL schemes: `com.you.your-other-app.1.0` and `com.you.your-other-app.1.2`.

You can then check if a specific version of that app is installed in any app using the following:

```
BOOL is10Installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"com.you.your-other-app.1.0://"]];
BOOL is12Installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"com.you.your-other-app.1.2://"]];
```

**Update:**
I use this in two of my apps that communicate between each other in order to determine whether a specific feature is supported or not. This can be quite useful.

Comment: Hi Fabian,
Thanks for your answer. Actually i had the idea of implement the URL Schemes, but this is not the best solution for me because my external app doesn't change the URL scheme each time. I need to read the bundle version to check if there's an update available.

Comment: I can change the url scheme each time when i have an update. That's maybe the only possible solution.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. ;)